# How to set featured image on different resolution

Tags: php, wordpress

How to set featured image on different resolutions in wordpress. I am trying this code, but it does not work. It generates full size of image.

```
<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
 $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'my_image_size', true);?>
    <a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-100x100" target="_blank">
        100x100
    </a>
 </br>
```

I have inserted this code into function.php `add_image_size( 'my_image_size', 300,125, true );`

I wanna look like [this url](http://www.hdwallpapers.in/anushka_sharma_new-wallpapers.html)

Comment: when I click 100x100 it's will generate 100x100 resolution Not full size. I dont know why this resolution are not working.

Comment: Did you have the image uploaded prior to adding this code, or did you add it after? because if you added it prior to the code, then wordpress did not create an image of `300x125` out of your upload.

Comment: I am using this code. it;s work fine. but iwant to resize features image on different resoltion that i have mention above link example.<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail', true);?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-15x150" target="_blank">150x150</a>
</br>
<?php
 $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'medium', true);?>
<a href="<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>" download="image-300x168" target="_blank">300x168</a>

</br>